# Make a picture from smaller tiles

Tags: automation, batch-processing, tiles

I really hope it is possible. I have 4,096 images. These images are relatively small (12 kb) and they are in TGA format.

Basically, these images are supposed to be small tiles of a 64×64 grid that I want to compile into a full picture for a game. I would love to know if there is a program that will connect all of them to a bigger picture.

Also, my pictures shall overlap each other by 16 px, is it possible to perhaps bulk-resize all their borders by 16 or to set and overlap for the mosaics for 16 px?

The pictures have names indicating their intended positions, if that helps:

```
img_000_000.tga
img_000_001.tga
img_000_002.tga
...
img_000_063.tga
img_001_000.tga
img_001_001.tga
img_001_002.tga
...
img_001_063.tga

...

img_063_063.tga
```

They go in the following order:

```
1   11  21  …
2   12  22  …
3   13  23  …
4   14  24  …
5   15  25  …
6   16  26  …
7   17  27  …
8   18  18  …
9   19  29  …
10  20  30  …
```

Comment: What have you tried? You can simply search "How to make your own photo mosaics" and there are plenty of results. Do the photos have to be in a specific order?

Comment: Yes, it goes down and then right:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize ImageMagick's [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command to make this easy. For an example, I split an image into 9 pieces and used a similar naming scheme:

[image: Images folder]

The following three commands will join them into three columns of images:

```
montage img_000_*.gif -tile 1x3 -geometry +0+0 col0.gif
montage img_001_*.gif -tile 1x3 -geometry +0+0 col1.gif
montage img_002_*.gif -tile 1x3 -geometry +0+0 col2.gif
```

[image: Images folder]

A final pass again with `montage` will join the columns together:

```
montage col*.gif -tile 3x1 -geometry +0+0 result.gif
```

[image: Humpty the cat]

I didn't simulate it in my example, but you can easily deal with overlapping borders as well. The [`geometry`](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage#geometry_spacing) flag will accept negative values, so try `-geometry -16-16` and see if that works for you.